# How can you backtrack through indexes of an array if element returned is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mapping

I'm working on a problem where I'm mapping through arrays returned from an API call to create an array of graph point objects, however the data returned is unreliable and contains null values. In order to simplify the question, here's a short version of what I have now:

```
const APITimestamps = ['123','124','125','126','127','128']
const APIPrices = ['22.34','22,45',NULL,NULL,'22.89','22.32']

const chartData = APITimestamps.map((timestamp, index) => {
let graphPoint = {}
graphPoint.timestamp = APITimestamps[index]
graphPoint.price = APIPrices[index]
return graphPoint
}
```

The map works as is, however I need to rid the chartData of the null values where the API does not have a price some of the timestamps. What I would like to do is backtrack through the indexes of APIPrices being mapped until a non-null value is found, which in the above case would be ['22.34','22,45','22,45','22,45','22.89','22.32']. Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop that iterates backwards from the current index and finds the first non-null value.

```js
const APITimestamps = ['123','124','125','126','127','128']
const APIPrices = ['22.34','22,45',null,null,'22.89','22.32']

const chartData = APITimestamps.map((timestamp, index) => {
  let graphPoint = {}
  graphPoint.timestamp = APITimestamps[index]
  for(let i = index; i >= 0; i--){
    if(APIPrices[i] !== null){
      graphPoint.price = APIPrices[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  return graphPoint
});
console.log(chartData);
```